# Understanding the Relation Between Delegation and Protocols

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, protocols

I know there are a lot of similar questions here but I still need some clarification about this concept.

First of all let me start by saying that I do understand what protocols are and how to use them, what I'm having problem understanding is delegation. I do understand that delegation is when one object in a program acts on behalf of another object, sound very simple but hard to see the whole picture.

1- Is delegation just a way to let the compiler know where to look for the code that will be manipulating the object (UITableView etc.)?

2- Do delegation and protocols work together?

3- Can delegation exist without protocols? If yes, can you show me an example.

4- When we declare a protocol and a class conforms to it, can we say that this class conforming to the protocol is delegating on behave of the protocol?

How much of the above is true?

Thanks a lot

Comment: A delegate is simply an instance of a class that implements methods which another class can call to fetch data from or perform actions on the first class.  A protocol is simply a convenient way to express the methods that are defined by the delegate.  There is no absolute need to use a protocol in a delegate scenario, and protocols can be used in other situations as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1- Is delegation just a way to let the compiler know where to look for the code that will be manipulating the object (UITableView etc.)?

No, delegation is a design pattern. It's just a concept.

> 2- Do delegation and protocols work together?

Yes they work well together and it's probably the best practice to use protocol for your delegate.

> 3- Can delegation exist without protocols? If yes, can you show me an example.

Yes you can. Delegation concept is just to remove intellect of an object and put it in the delegate. For exemple an `UITableView` does not know how many row it has, or what to do when a cell is clicked, so it asks to its delegate.
But the delegate is still another object.

It's better if it implements a particular protocol, but you can do it without.

*For exemple :*

I've a MyView that is a subview of a `MyCustomViewController`.

**MyCustomViewController.h**

```
- (void)myViewIsTouched;
```

**MyView.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) MyCustomViewController *delegate
```

**MyView.m**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.delegate myViewIsTouched];
}
```

There is no protocol in this exemple, but it's still a delegate.
(A better way is still using a protocol instead of declaring the method in the `.h`)

> 4- When we declare a protocol and a class conforms to it, can we say that this class conforming to the protocol is delegating on behave of the protocol?

I'm not sure about what're saying. But protocols and delegate are not the same thing. An object implementing a protocol does not mean that it's a delegate.

Comment: I think it starting to make sense, one more question. Since delegation can exist without protocols, does that means that in theory any class can be the delegate of another class and there is no distinction or special keyword as far as class declaration?  in other words a class doesn't need to be declared as delegator or delegee, correct? I hope my question make sense. Thanks

Comment: @fs_tigre Sure, any object can be the delegate of another one. There is no special delegate keyword. The only mandatory thing is to have the possibility for the delegated to call its delegate.
But the best way to implement them is to follow what Apple use in `UIKit`.
The delegate of an object is a property called `delegate` and implements a particular sets of method (protocol).

Answer (score 1):

1. *Delegation* allows objects to be able to change their appearance / state based on changes in other parts of your application. Setting a
   `delegate` property on an object will allow the compiler to do some
   checks at build-time.
2. Delegation is often achieved by using protocols, since it allows the
   delegate object to be of any class instead of a sub-class of a class
   with specific behaviour.
3. Yes, but this would result in your classes becoming tightly coupled since `Foo` needs to know about `Bar` and vice-versa. Using protocols allows you to use any class, hence `id` property, resulting in a loosely coupled system.

Example:

```
@class Foo;
@interface Bar : NSObject
- (void)respondToSomeAction:(Foo *)obj;
@end

@implementation Bar 
- (void)respondToSomeAction:(Foo *)obj {
   NSLog("responding to %@",obj);
}
@end

@interface Foo : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, weak) Bar *delegate
@end

@implementation Foo
- (void)someActionTriggered {
    [self.delegate respondToSomeAction:self]
}
@end
```

4. When a class conforms to a protocol, the class is compelled to adopt the behaviours of the protocol (implement the methods). It only becomes a *delegate* if it is given some task to do on behalf of another class, e.g. supply the number of rows in a table.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your code in Swift but I'm not sure how to do the property assignment `(@property (nonatomic, weak) Bar *delegate)` in Swift. Can you please create a similar example of the above code in Swift? Thanks